# A navigationcontroller appears out of no where when I create a segue to logout - Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, segue

So I placed a logout button, and created a segue to the first view controller where users can either log in or sign up. For some reason, when I created the segue, in the first view controller appeared a navigation controller, as if it were embedded, but it's not. If I delete the segue, the navigation disappears. I tried creating a new button, but the same problem appears. Here's a screenshot of how the navigation appears in my app. P.S I am using Swift

[Image here. Notice the navigation controller.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBpfw.png)

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me figure this out.

Comment: Navigation Will show if you are segue from a controller which came in existence using a Navigation controller , You need to manage now to show or hide navigation bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand, `UINavigationController` properly. No matter `UINavigationController` is initial or not, but from where you are creating segue, there must exist `UINavigationController`. So, you are getting a `UINavigationBar` and a back button.

You can still disable that from `UIStoryboard` by selecting Top Bar to `None`.

[image]

Well, if you wish to do it from coding then do it via following way in your `ViewController` class:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
}
```

Let me know, if you still face any issue.

Comment: omg! Thanks! I had to use both! The top bar AND the viewWillAppear! Worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi Sohil! I was wondering if you could help me resolve some other issues through email. I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Shoot at sohil.spaceo@gmail.com